# How to check condition of xml value?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have two rules I want to implement in the  XML application.

> 1 If weight is bigger then 10 then by name Department has to be
> written: Big

Comment: Why don't you check the properties if they meet the condition and if they do the append the department string token to the result string? This is not a complicated problem.

Comment: You can even inline the conditional check.

Comment: Yes but it will be cleaner to use some patterns for this. But I am stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to let the `Department` property itself compute its value (computed property). This is cleaner and more readable as the computation takes place where you would expect it. Otherwise in a scenarion where the computation depends on more than a single property you would find yourself writing duplicate computational code in each participating property.
Therefore, execute the computation when the value is requested - which is when the computed property's `Get()` is called - and not when the partzicipating properties have changed. If the computation is more complex, then following this rules will improve performance too.

Also avoid implementing such a filter directly in the `Set()`/`Get()` of a property. Move it to a method.

I also suggest using a switch-statement or switch-expression as this is more readable than a long chain of if-else blocks and therefore easier to maintain. When using C# 9, then switch-expression can be a powerful tool to filter with a nicely readable syntax.

Furthermore, since the string you are trying to create for thze print out is a fixed `string` representation of the actual `Parcel` instance, it would be more appropriate to override the `Parcel.ToString`.

Your Parcel class should look like something this:

**Parcel.cs**

```
public class Parcel
{
  public override string ToString() 
    => $"Name: {this.Name} - Postal code {this.PostalCode} - Weight {this.Weight} - Value {this.Value} - Department {this.Department}";

  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string PostalCode { get; set; }
  public decimal Weight { get; set; }
  public decimal Value { get; set; }
  public string Department => CreateDepartmentValue();

  private string CreateDepartmentValue()
  {
    var result = string.Empty;

    switch (this.Weight)
    {
      case decimal weightInKiloGrams when weightInKiloGrams <= 1: result = "Mail"; break;
      case decimal weightInKiloGrams when weightInKiloGrams <= 10: result = "Regular"; break;
      case decimal weightInKiloGrams when weightInKiloGrams > 10: result = "Heavy"; break;
    };


    switch (this.Value)
    {
      case decimal value when value > 1000: result += ", Insurance"; break;
    };

    return result;
  }
}
```

### Usage Example

```
public class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load($"Container.xml");
    var items = ...;

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
      // Call ToString() implicitly
      Console.WriteLine(item);
      Console.WriteLine("*********************************************************************");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Create a class Parcel and determine the Department based on Weight & value from function call

```
public class Parcel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public string Department => GetDepartment();
    private string GetDepartment()
    {
        string _department = "";
        if (this.Weight <= 1)
        {
            _department = "Mail";
        }
        else if (this.Weight > 1 && this.Weight <= 10)
        {
            _department = "Regular";
        }
        else if (this.Weight > 10)
        {
            _department = "Heavy";
        }
        else
        {
            _department = "Unknown";
        }

        if (this.Value > 1000)
        {
            _department += ",Insurance";
        }

        return _department;
    }
}
```

Your `XDcoument` will look like below

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load($"XMLFile1.xml");

var items = xdoc.Descendants("Parcel")
                .Select(xelem => new Parcel
                {
                    Name = xelem.Element("Sender").Element("Name").Value,
                    PostalCode = xelem.Element("Sender").Element("Address").Element("PostalCode").Value,
                    Weight = Convert.ToDecimal(xelem.Element("Weight").Value),
                    Value = Convert.ToDecimal(xelem.Element("Value").Value)
                });

foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{ item.Name} - { item.PostalCode} - { item.Weight} - { item.Value} - { item.Department}");
}
```

Output

```
Klaas - 2402AE - 0.02 - 0.0 - Mail
ykken groot B.V. - 2497GA - 2.0 - 0.0 - Regular
seti - 2497GA - 100.0 - 2000.0 - Heavy,Insurance
Aad - 2353HS - 11 - 500 - Heavy
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. But if I want to add one condition more, like this:  Department =
                            Convert.ToDecimal(xelem.Element("Weight").Value) <=1 ? "Mail" :

                                Convert.ToDecimal(xelem.Element("Weight").Value) > 1000 ? "Large" :
                                 Convert.ToDecimal(xelem.Element("Weight").Value) > 10 ? "Big" : "Small"
                 }); then it is not working

Comment: I dont see the name Mail then

Comment: @mightycodeNewton, I have updated the post with more efficient way

Comment: Hi Krishna, thank you. I updated the post. Can you have a final look at it. I also changes some code. Thank you

Comment: Yes, the first parcel  of the output it says 2. But the value in xml is 0.02

Comment: You are not looking at right output.. The output looks for me good

Comment: Also your if-else logic is flawed. For example if any `Weight` condition evaluates to `true` then the `Value` condition is droppped.

Comment: @BionicCode, good point, have updated the post

Comment: But you are now overriding the _department value instead of appending it to the weight related string

Comment: Hi Krishna, thank you for all your effort.

Comment: This looks much better. Now your solution makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

Why not extend your Parcel class to have a 'DepartmentSize' property, which handles the size:

```
class Parcel
{
     public string DepartmentSize 
     {
         var parts = new List<string>();
         if(_Weight> 10)
             parts.Append("Big");
         if(_Value > 1000) 
             parts.Append("Large");
         return string.Join(",", parts);
     }
 }
```

Then you can output the size like this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"... Department: {item.DepartmentSize}");
```

Comment: Thank you. But how is this connected? I mean  class Parcel is not used at the moment

Comment: You are correct, your Parcel class is not being used.  I thought it was.  That being said, in your Program, instead of creating an anonymous type, why not create a collection of Parcels (using the constructor), then my solution will work.

Comment: You mean a ParcelHandler?